# EntityDataSource CommandText Count Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, entitydatasource

This simple piece of sql works perfect in sql server...

```
Select it.Id as Id, it.Status as Status,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM PickLocations as pl WHERE pl.PickBatchItemId = bi.Id) AS Counts
FROM PickBatches AS it
INNER JOIN PickBatchItems as bi ON it.Id = bi.PickBatchId
```

Gives me...

```
Id, Status, Counts
-------------------
1    1       2
2    1       0
3    2       2
```

But after making a change so that it wont complain...

```
Select it.Id as Id, it.Status as Status,
    (SELECT COUNT (pl.Id) FROM PickLocations AS pl WHERE bi.Id == pc.PickBatchItemId) AS Count
FROM PickBatches AS it
INNER JOIN PickBatchItems as bi ON it.Id == bi.PickBatchId
```

when I use this in a EntityDataSource CommandText I get...

```
Id, Status, Counts
-------------------
1    1       System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord]
2    1       System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord]
3    2       System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord]
```

Obviously missing something simple...

**UPDATE**

Problem solved by Vikram.

Using select **value** count() and getting the index of the count with **Count[0]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **VALUE** to the nested `SELECT` returned a list of Int32 instead.

Binding like this, returned the value:

```
Count='<%# Eval("Count[0]") %>'
```

Comment: I remember trying that and I got - System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord

Comment: can you show me the code where you used Count[0]? i have edited my answer

Comment: I am using a ListView and binding in a Lable like this - <asp:Label ID="CountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Count[0]") %>' />

Comment: add VALUE to your nest select list: SELECT VALUE COUNT (pl.Id) FROM PickLocations AS pl WHERE bi.Id == pc.PickBatchItemId